# Sed for parsing

Tags: sed

I have file:

```
"data_personnel": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Mathieu"
    }
],
"struct_hospital": [
    {
        "id": "9",
        "geo": "chamb",
        "nb": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "",
        "geo": "jsj",
        "nb": "SMITH"
    },
    {
        "id": "10",
        "geo": "",
        "nb": "12"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "geo": "marqui",
        "nb": "20"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "geo": "oliwo",
        "nb": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "geo": "par",
        "nb": "5"
    }
]
```

How to use sed for for to have all the values ​​of geo in struct_hospital? (chamb, jsj, , marqui, oliwo, etc ..)
The file can be in any form. With tabs, everything on a line, etc ..

Comment: if this is json, don't use sed.. use parsers like `jq`... also, add code you've tried to question..

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Sundeep, it makes more sense to use a proper JSON parser.
But if you are looking for a one-time quick and dirty solution, then this might do:

```
sed -n '/^"struct_hospital"/,/^]/s/^.*"geo"\s*:\s*"\([^"]*\)"\s*,\?.*$/\1/p' input.txt
```

Sample output:

```
chamb
jsj

marqui
oliwo
par
```

Explanation:

- `/^"struct_hospital"/,/^]/` - only consider lines between `struct_hospital` and the closing bracket.
- `s/.../\1/p` search and replace; only print the first capturing subpattern of every matching line
- `^.*"geo"\s*:\s*"\(.*\)"\s*,\?.*$` matches the `geo` lines; captures the value following the colon

In case the input spans a single line, you can use another `sed` invocation as a preprocessor to insert line breaks:

```
sed 's/]\|,/\n&/g'
```

This makes the full command:

```
sed 's/]\|,/\n&/g' input.txt | sed -n '/^"struct_hospital"/,/^]/s/^.*"geo"\s*:\s*"\([^"]*\)"\s*,\?.*$/\1/p'
```

Comment: `The file can be in any form. With tabs, everything on a line, etc ..`

Comment: @Kent I misread the question and was under the false impression that OP meant the desired output could be in any format. I edited my answer; thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: I use this comment `sed -n "/\"struct_hospital\"/,/^\],$/s/^[[:blank:]]*\"geo\":[[:blank:]]\+\"\([^\"]*\)\",/\1/p my_file` but it's don't work if I want to get all value of nb ...